# 74hc165 serial output goes to 5v

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, digital-logic, esp32

I Seem to be having problems as soon as I unplug the esp32 from usb and power it from external power.

Don’t think this is normal but when running on external power the 74hc165 serial output goes to 5v when the button is clicked, when its running on usb power the serial output is really low voltage "17.7mV when clicked 12.0mV not clicked" and everything runs as it should.

As far as I know it would be bad sending 5v back into the esp32 pin
Not sure if its something simple that I have missed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing weird going on.

A chip powered from 5V will have 5V logic levels on it's outputs and it requires 5V logic levels on it's inputs.

The problem is, feeding in 5V into 3.3V MCU that is not designed to handle 5V IO is not a good idea and may cause the MCU to damage. So don't do that.

No device on breaboard requires 5V so use 3.3V.

Comment: It will be moved from a bread board and all powered from 5V once i work out everything, I have other devices that need 5V.

Comment: i Edited my post a little. but i think its werid that my serial output voltage is so different when running from external power, im using 5v pin

Comment: @fiven80440 The point is, you can't send 5V to 3.3V MCU. The 5V is a supply input to module. Don't use it for anything that ends up sending 5V to MCU IO pins, you will damage it.

Comment: Yeah thats why im asking, what is the best way to stop this? while running most of the things on 5V. also if i changed the ttp223 for a push button i dont get this high voltage, so i was asking how come im getting weird voltage with a ttp when on external power vs internal 5v

Comment: Do not use 5V. For two reasons. It is not an output but an input where you can connect a power supply if you don't use USB. I don't know the details as you need schematics for the board how it connects to anything, but it is possible it is only same as USB VBUS maybe so it only outputs 5V when USB is connected. Second, do not power things at 5V because the MCU damages when 5V is sent to inputs capable only for 3.3V. Use 3.3V for everything.

Comment: but i need to run 5v, and 74hc165 supports 5v, so shouldnt i just convert the serial output of the 74hc165 to 3.3v?

Comment: @fiven80440 everything supports 3V3 so why bother converting if everything can be run on 3.3V. Also, when the 74HC165 is run at 5V, it does not support 3.3V clock and load inputs from MCU so you would have to then level convert those up from 3.3V to 5V. It requires at least 3.5V to work and 3.3V is not enough.

Comment: i have added a 74hc125 buffer to make clock and load 5v, i need 5v because i am using 5v leds that are closer to the 74hc165, and a cable to the esp32

Comment: @fiven80440 Aha, so you are not telling the whole circuit so we can't know what you do. Where are the LEDs connected and why they need 5V? Also the HC125 also can't accept 3.3V signals when 5V supply so you can pretty much forget that idea. All HC chips are specced like that. Use 3.3V for logic, use different LEDs, do the translation only for LEDs and run a separate 5V wire for LEDs.

Comment: So i could just use 74hct125 it says that accepts 3.3v as far as i can see

Comment: or is there other chips that would do the same thing that accept 3.3v input and output 5v?

Comment: HCT is fine but you are still left with level shifting the 5V down to 3.3V for MCU input. You know you could have a 3.3V regulator on the far side so only 5V wire is between boards